# How to solve this equation: $e^x=(\sqrt{y}+1)^2$ for y?

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus

We have $e^x=(\sqrt{y}+1)^2$. I tried to solve this equation for y, but I'm stuck 
when I get the expression: $e^x= y + 2\sqrt{y}+1$ because there is still an root of y. Can someone give me a step-by-step solution for this problem?

Comment: added more correct tag (algebra-precalculus)

Answer (score 2):

taking the square root on both sides we get
$$\sqrt {e^x}=\sqrt{y}+1$$
squaring again we have
$$y=\left(\sqrt{e^x}-1\right)^2$$